# How to setup a maven project to run on a remote java platform?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Netbeans IDE provides a way to add a remote java platform and run projects on it. 
I have tried this on a maven project imported in Netbeans, but wasn't able to see any  possible way to run the project on a remote java platform. Is this possible at all?

The reason i need this setup is because the main machine for development is shared by many developers. As i am developing a very CPU and memory intensive application,  running or debugging on the main machine is nigh improbable.